# Importing pandas from a location for version python2.6.6

Tags: python

I installed pandas 0.16.2 using this command

pip install --target /myfolder [packages]

Now, i want to write a python script to import pandas from the /myfolder

My code

```
import imp
pd  =imp.load_source('pandas.name','/mnt/gfsusr/software/python_modules/pandas')
pd
```

I expect that the pd variable above contains all the methods of pandas.

Comment: I suggest you to implement a virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/mnt/gfsusr/software')

from python_modules import pandas as pd
```

The code above will extend the sys path to include the file you want to import.